# ¿Cómo reproducir notas musicales con python?

Tags: python-3.7, sonido

Quisiera saber si hay una herramienta de python que me permita hacer sonar notas musicales, algo en donde solo mande la frecuencia y la duración, tipo así:

sonido(1000Hz,0.20seg)

Pero también me gustaría poder hacer sonar varias notas al mismo tiempo y que suenen una detrás de otra, ya que quiero crear compases pero las herramientas que he encontrado para música en python solo funcionan descargando archivos y yo no quiero eso.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que hacer una distinción que con sólo la frecuencia y la duración no es suficiente para hacer un sonido. Si no que falta determinar las características de la onda a generar.

Recordemos la diferencia entre el sonido de una guitarra y de una flauta, a un caso más fundamental entre una onda sinusoidal y una onda dientes de cierra.

Acotando tu pregunta, me imagino que te refieres a ondas sinusoidales, que son las más comunes y fáciles de generar. Ahí a generar el sonido de otros instrumentos la complejidad varía.

Habiendo contextualizado, puedo decirte que desde mi experiencia no existe alguna suite de composición o síntesis con un banco de sonidos muy amplio; si no, como tu dices existen algunos que permiten importar tus muestras y aplicarles diversos filtros y transformaciones.

Lo que buscas es un sintentizador de audio y lo más cercano a lo que buscas es [synthesizer](https://pypi.org/project/synthesizer/), que presenta varios presets de generadores de ondas y formas de reproducirlas.